# Can units join a character in combat?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I know a character can join a unit.

Can a unit join a character?

Can a unit join a character that is in close combat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From BRB p97.

A character must move into a unit to join it.  There is no rule that allows the unit to move to the character.

A character cannot join a unit in close combat.

You can however, simply charge into combat alongside the character.  This is often to your advantage for that particular combat, other than not being able to use the character's leadership.  (Two chances to catch the enemy if they flee, if one or the other of yours flees, the other may hold and prevent them form being run down, etc.)

Comment: A word of warning (as a lot of your other questions are undead related) if you charge a weak skeleton unit in to support a big vampire and it suffers a lot of casualties the damage it can do to your combat res can often be enough to kill your character with the unstable rule!